# Looking for a good Emacs C++ tagging

Tags: c++, tags, emacs23

I have used emacs for the past 25 years. I don't use it currently since I cannot find how to tag effectively a large C++ code base.

I had to resort to slickedit just because of its superior tagging. I hate it as an editor, but in this large project I must have the following functionality:

1. references - standing on classApointer->size() or Aobject.size() I want to see all uses of the size function of class A
2. definition - take me to the definition/declaration of size() of class A

in emacs, useing etags, gtags, all I can get are huge lists of size() candidates. Not good enough. Is there any tagging system that works well with c++ and can do what I need in emacs?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I used CEDET (http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) once before, it seemed to do a decent job of adding some ide-like features for C/C++ development. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by tagging though.

Comment: This is not a good fit to our Q&A format. Please consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: @CollinHockey: I have used a recent version of CEDET and never got it to be fast enough or easily used enough. I would say its not worth to bother with it. Instead I would skip Emacs and go for Eclipse CDT, but thats ofcourse not in the scope of the question

Comment: I use CEDET/semantic with `semantic-symref`, `semantic-complete-jump`, `semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle`, `senator-go-to-up-reference`, etc. Try cscope [emacs wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs), it doesn't support c++ type system well but maybe produce more appropriate results for you. Also, look at this: [SilentBob](http://silentbob.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: goto-defininition is easiest with esc-< + C-s ::MyFunction. (but that one requires big files + remembering which file it is in)